# Can I say: It's of hers?

Tags: possessive-pronouns

A common expression I know is *A friend of mine* like in: *I studied math with a friend of mine.* A possessive pronoun is used with the noun *friend.

Is it grammatically correct to use the same pattern in a situation like this:
A:  Whose book is this?
B: **It's of hers**.
I know that the most common answer would be *It's **hers**.* But, is it possible to say: It's ***of**** hers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. But you *can sometimes* say "it's a book of hers".

The reason for this, as well as the reason this syntax isn't used in most sentences, is that it places the **emphasis of the phrase on the noun** ("book" or "friend"). Which means **all the other information must already be known**: the object being referred to, and the person it belongs to, but *not* the object's identity.

So in "he's a friend of mine," the listener already knows that there is a *he* who has some relationship with the speaker, but not what that relationship is. "It's a book of hers" would *not* sound natural in the context you described because the object's identity is known but its owner is not.

Edit: I didn't even think of Peter's suggestion, but I think his answer is more relevant than mine.

Answer (score 1):

"It's of hers" is wrong, but "it's *one* of hers" is correct. The original pattern you gave was "*noun* of hers", but there was no *noun* in that position in the sentence you asked about. It is correct to use *one* instead of the missing noun.

Answer (score 0):

I would answer that question "no". Even if you were talking about material someone actually wrote and not just a copy they happen to own.